# Is there any Azure service similar to AWS Systems Manager Session Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm, bastion-host

AWS SSM Agent can be installed on private subnet VMs allowing access to the EC2 instance through AWS EC2 console.

Described here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/

Additionally, with AWS VPC Endpoints for Systems Manager using AWS PrivateLink a session can be opened directly to a VM in a private subnet.

Described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-privatelink.html

Which allows a local terminal session to be established to a VM in a private subnet.

I have looked for similar access in Azure but haven't found anything quite like Systems Manager Session Manager like what is provided by AWS.

The closest thing I have been able to find is Azure Bastion service:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-bastion/#features

And Azure Cloud Shell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview

But what I am looking for is a method to connect from a terminal on a local machine to a private subnet VM without the need for a private / public key method over ssh.

Is there any such method available in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

- Since you don't want to connect to VM using the azure bastion and SSH   with public and private key, a different alternative would be the use of the RDP.
- RDP stands for remote desktop protocol, to connect to the VM using   RDP we need to download a  `.rdp` file from the azure portal.
- The file is in the connect section of the azure portal of the VM.

Once downloaded run the file and give access to the subsequent prompts.

Before that you need to enable remote desktop by going to
**Settings** > **System** > **Remote Desktop**

Refer the following [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon#:%7E:text=1%20Go%20to%20the%20Azure%20portal%20to%20connect,the%20virtual%20machine%20and%20finish%20logging%20on.%20?msclkid=0ab98e49b4c711ec9e86cb3c35ed5c1b) for detailed info.

Comment: I am sorry I failed to mention, these are Linux instances that we intend to connect to, not Windows.  Is there any solution for Linux instances?